# How to create a jar for specific package?

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, packaging

i have a maven desktop project, and it consists of several packages, and i was wondering if it's possible to extract one of the packages as a separate jar, so i can reuse it, instead of making a new project that contains only this package ?

Comment: I'd rather recommend creating a separate project for the mentioned package. Why don't you like this separation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `includes` parameter in the [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/jar-mojo.html) to achieve this.  In fact the [usage page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html) has an example on how to do this.

You could do this within a `profile` so that you can continue to build the normal project with all classes.

Comment: i think that all what i am going to need is the following to be added to the jar plugin, right ?: `<executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <classifier>client</classifier>
              <includes>
                <include>**/service/*</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>`

Comment: @SamehFarahat Yes, that's the example I referred to.